# Manually entering number instead of text field in swift

Tags: swift

I want to print "Best Country" based on numbers in swift

for example : - if i enter " 1 " it will print "Best". if i enter " 2 " it 
will print " Country ". For 1 and 2 it will print " Best Country ".

how to manually enter numbers in swift ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: No i am not asking any one to write code . i want any one to help me how to enter number manually like "c" language without textfield

Comment: Yes i am writting it in swift playground. but how to do it ?

Comment: You can't read keyboard input from within a playground. Create a command line tool and use `readLine()`

Answer (score 1):

As per the OP it seems a project with console input/output is desired. To input values from console. You need to create a console based project with swift selected as Language.

**Xcode -> New -> Project...** 
then select appropriate option as in screenshot below :
[image]

Press Next and then fill in the required details (project Name etc...)